# Why $\nabla\ln x=\nabla x/x$ include the $\nabla x$ in the numerator?

Tags: calculus

Reading a book I came across this identity:

$\nabla  \ln(x) = \frac{\nabla x}{x}$

I understand that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $x$, but I don't understand why the gradient (which is a vector of partial derivatives) of $\ln(x)$ is equal to $\nabla x$ divided by $x$. Is it because of the chain rule?

Comment: The derivative of $In(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:$$\nabla f(x)=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}e^i=f^\prime(x)\sum_i\frac{\partial x}{\partial y^i}e^i=f^\prime(x)\nabla x. $$

Comment: J.G. Thank you for your answer, I have two questions, 1) the $e$ where it come from? I was expecting a vector of the partial derivatives of $f(x)$ , 2) is a summation another way to represent the gradient?

Comment: @Pulse9 The $e^i$ comprise a basis of the vector space in which $\nabla f$ lives, so $\nabla f$ is a sum of multiples of the $e^i$; the coefficients in this sum as the components of $\nabla f$. Alternatively, we can equate $i$th components of $\nabla f(x)=f^\prime(x)\nabla_x$ viz. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}=f^\prime(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial y^i}$, again by teh chain rule.